# Why can't I select any higher resolution?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

For some reason I seem to be unable to select any higher resolution when trying to play the game in fullscreen mode.

Despite my screen supporting up to 2560×1440 pixels, the maximum I get is 1280×1024, which isn't even 1080p:

[image: Graphics settings from the game]

When playing in windowed mode, I'm at least able to pick up to 1920×1200. While this isn't perfect, it's better than playing with a blurry screen.

What's the reason behind this and is there some way to fix it?

Comment: What graphics API are you using Mantle or Direct X?

Comment: In my case DirectX 11, although I'd imagine it's the same with Mantle as well (can't test due to having an Nvidia card).

Answer (score 3):

So far: No. There's no way to correct this.

[The developers are aware of the issue, yet we'll have to wait for a patch to correct this.](https://twitter.com/CivGame/status/525444246372114432)

In theory, it should be possible to open the file

```
<Documents>\My Games\Sid Meier's Civilization Beyond Earth\GraphicsSettings.ini
```

with your favorite text editor and look for the entries `WindowResX`, `WindowResY`, `Refresh Rate`, and `FullScreen`.

However, it seems like the game has some issue with screens providing refresh rates higher than 60 Hz, which obviously causes it to fail to display or accept only a limited amount of resolution/refresh rate combinations.

The higher the maximum resolution and refresh rate your screen supports, the more likely it is that you won't be able to utilize it right now.

As a temporary workaround, continue playing in windowed mode or connect a screen that won't support anything higher than 60 Hz.